# Java-OOP: Why Java hides protected methods from super class instance in sub class?

Tags: java, oop

Ok. I have these two classes:

```
class A{

    private static A myA = new A();

    protected void a()
    {
         //some stuff
    }
    protected void test(){
        myA.a(); //Hello I see you
    }
}

class B extends A{

    private static A myA = new A();

    public void test()
    {
        myA.a(); //Eclipse error: Oopse a() is not visible.
    }
}
```

I have defined the class A and a sub-class B.
Inside A like we all know, I can create an instance of a and have access to everything including protected method a().

B is a sub-class of A and thus have access to protected members.
But if I create an instance of A inside B, and then try to access method a() from that instance, eclipse complains that protected method is not visible.

Why is that? Is't that both class A and B are considered the same type for protected members?

Now if I change class b to:

```
 class B extends A{

    private static B myA = new B();/*I kept the name as myA to show the point*/

    public void test()
    {
        myA.a(); //Hello, I see you now
    }
}
```

I changed the type of myA to B, inside B. Now B is able to access the protected method a() from the myA instance. While I expected B to be able to access all protected methods of instances of A and don't see it as a violation of encapsulation.

Comment: Assuming `A` and `B` are meant to be in different packages.

Comment: thank you Sotirios Delimanolis